# How to get the 32bit version of IDL virtual machine in my target with Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I need to add idl virtual machine to my Target location for my IDL .sav file I am using Inno Setup, And the following code lines:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\clas"; Filename: "{code:GetIDLPath}"; Parameters: "{code:GetIDLParams}"; IconFilename: "{app}\clas_icon.ico"

[Code]
function GetIDLPath(Value: string): string;
begin

  RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\idlrt.exe', '', Result);
  if Result = '' then
    Result := 'idlrt.exe';
end;

function GetIDLParams(Value: string): string;
begin
  // prepare the -vm option followed by a quoted application path to a file
  Result := '-vm ' + AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{app}\bin\BATCH_CLAS_MAIN.sav'));
  // and replace backslashes to forward slashes
  StringChangeEx(Result, '\', '/', False);
end;
```

This code will give me the location for the 64bit IDL virtual machine exe file and not the 32 bit version as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL82\bin\bin.x86_64\idlrt.exe" -vm C:/clas/bin/BATCH_CLAS_MAIN.sav
```

But I need:

```
"C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL82\bin\bin.x86\idlrt.exe" -vm C:/clas/bin/BATCH_CLAS_MAIN.sav
```

I have checked both these locations:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\idlrt.exe
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\idlrt.exe
```

And they both only have the 64bit version path.

Does anyone know how to get he 32bit version path?

Comment: Does this IDL add any other registry keys? E.g. in uninstall or somewhere else (not only in App Paths)? You can always `ExtractFileDir` and then build new string with check if `FileExists`.

Comment: Regarding other registry entries, you could Search for `C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL82` to see if there are others than App Paths.

Comment: I searched the registry for idlrt.exe, and only the 64bit version showed up in multiple locations, but NOT the 32bit version.

Comment: Do not look for EXE, because there may not be path to 32bit EXE on 64bit OS. Look for IDL main path and then build string like `Full32bitPath := ExpandConstant(IDLMainPath) + '\bin\bin.x86\idlrt.exe';` and then do `FileExists` check to be sure that file is on it's place.

Comment: How do i just get IDLMainPath? what should i be searching for?

Comment: Look for `C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL82` in registry. That is IDL Main Path in your case. Probably it may be found in IDL registry branch (if created by installer) or in Uninstall section.

Comment: So i found inside HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs a binary data path: C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL82\bin\bin.x86\idlrt.exe; So how do i use that in the code?

Comment: Using shared DLL key is not a solution. I would definitely look for Registry key with just IDL Main Path. Is there really no, even a single key, pointing to IDL Main Path? If I could download IDL I could check that. In my opinion there has to be path e.g. in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Comment: not really no keys, only binaries, and those two paths dont give back an uninstall version for 32bit.

Comment: Show me your `Uninstall` branch. There has to be registry entry for Exelis IDL if it is installed...

Comment: For example : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs has the binary C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL82\bin\bin.x86\idlrt.exe, but i cant find a registry key that has C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL82\, is that what you mean?

Comment: can i extract the binary information from the registry key?

Comment: This is not uninastall. As in here the path is in the `ValueName`, not the `ValueData`, you would have to `look in loop` through all keys in `SharedDLLs` to find `idlrt.exe` and then `extract` this `ValueName` as `String`. Not a good solution.

Comment: So you want me to find an uninstall registry key inside  C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL82\bin\bin.x86\, is that what you mean?

Comment: No. In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninst‌​all` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` or you should search for `idlrt.exe` in loop for `SharedDLLs` and then extract the path when EXE found. Further messages in comments make no sense. We should either move to chat or abandon the topic...

Comment: What do you want me to search there for: C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL82\

Comment: The Uninstall Branch In The Registry. If you have installed Exelis IDL, there has to be Uninstall Registry Entry for this Application. In this entry there is a great chance to find App path. Or just slice (`ExtractFileDir`) your 64bit path and add 32bit folder as I have mentioned at the beginning. Sorry, I'm out.

Comment: @RobeN, that makes no sense. Consider what happens if the user installs the 64-bit version to a totally different directory than the 32-bit one. And, you don't need any single entry in registry for an uninstaller. It's not a requirement. Yes, you wouldn't see the application in Control Panel's Programs applet, but if you don't need that, there's no need to write anything to registry.

Comment: @TLama - that is not possible. It is 1 app that has 2 different sets of EXEs included, which are ALWAYS in the same main Dir. `{app}\bin\bin.x86_64` and `{app}\bin\bin.x86`. So that make perfectly sense to `ExtractFileDir` or to `StringChange`. And if the App does not create ANY reg entries, then the only way to find it is to scan all HardDrives... (that makes no sense).